# Problemas con php a la hora de crear un projecto CakePhp 3 con composer

Tags: php, cakephp, composer

Estoy tratando de crear un proyecto de cakephp3 en una maquina con linux mint (ubuntu 16) pero tengo problemas con el php e revisado varios post en internet y hice lo que decían pero parece no surtir efecto espero ver si alguien aquí puede saber que ocurre.

[image: Error composer]

aqui esta mi versión de php 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este composer lo e usado para instalar otras cosas pero es la primera vez que me da estos errores

Answer (score 1):

Instala php7.0-intl . Cuando hagas el apt-get install php7 pulsa el tabulador para q te aparezcan los paquetes q puedes instalar. Ente ellos tienes q instalar el php7.0-mbstring también.